# Mac is getting slower. Because of pyenv or zsh, bash setting?

Tags: oh-my-zsh, pyenv

Suddenly my terminal is getting slower seriously!
I don't know why but I guess the cause is that something wrong pyenv or zsh, bash setting.

Here is my **pyenv log** When I run `ls` in Terminal(zsh).

```
+_pyenv_virtualenv_hook:1> local 'ret=0'                                                                                               
+_pyenv_virtualenv_hook:2> [ -n '' ']'
+_pyenv_virtualenv_hook:5> pyenv sh-activate --quiet
+pyenv:1> local command
+pyenv:2> command=sh-activate 
+pyenv:3> [ 2 -gt 0 ']'
+pyenv:4> shift
+pyenv:7> case sh-activate (activate | deactivate | rehash | shell)
+pyenv:7> case sh-activate (*)
+pyenv:11> pyenv sh-activate --quiet
+ [pyenv:23] enable -f /usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/20160202/libexec/../libexec/pyenv-realpath.dylib realpath
+ [pyenv:29] '[' -z '' ']'
++ [pyenv:31] type -p greadlink readlink
++ [pyenv:31] head -1
+ [pyenv:31] READLINK=/usr/bin/readlink
+ [pyenv:32] '[' -n /usr/bin/readlink ']'
+ [pyenv:53] '[' -z '' ']'
+ [pyenv:54] PYENV_ROOT=/Users/DS/.pyenv
+ [pyenv:58] export PYENV_ROOT
+ [pyenv:61] '[' -z '' ']'
+ [pyenv:62] '[' -n '' ']'
+ [pyenv:73] '[' -z '' ']'
+ [pyenv:74] PYENV_DIR=/Users/DS
+ [pyenv:80] export PYENV_DIR
+ [pyenv:83] shopt -s nullglob
++ [pyenv:85] abs_dirname /usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/20160202/libexec/pyenv
++ [pyenv:39] local cwd=/Users/DS
++ [pyenv:40] local path=/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/20160202/libexec/pyenv
++ [pyenv:42] '[' -n /usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/20160202/libexec/pyenv ']'
++ [pyenv:43] cd /usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/20160202/libexec
++ [pyenv:44] local name=pyenv
+++ [pyenv:45] resolve_link pyenv
+++ [pyenv:35] /usr/bin/readlink pyenv
+++ [pyenv:45] true
++ [pyenv:45] path=
++ [pyenv:42] '[' -n '' ']'
++ [pyenv:48] pwd
++ [pyenv:49] cd /Users/DS
+ [pyenv:85] bin_path=/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/20160202/libexec
+ [pyenv:89] export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/20160202/libexec:/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv-virtualenv/20160202/shims:/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/20160202/libexec:/Users/DS/.pyenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin
+ [pyenv:89] PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/20160202/libexec:/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv-virtualenv/20160202/shims:/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/20160202/libexec:/Users/DS/.pyenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin
+ [pyenv:91] PYENV_HOOK_PATH=:/Users/DS/.pyenv/pyenv.d
+ [pyenv:92] '[' /usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/20160202 '!=' /Users/DS/.pyenv ']'
+ [pyenv:94] PYENV_HOOK_PATH=:/Users/DS/.pyenv/pyenv.d:/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/20160202/pyenv.d
+ [pyenv:96] PYENV_HOOK_PATH=:/Users/DS/.pyenv/pyenv.d:/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/20160202/pyenv.d:/usr/local/etc/pyenv.d:/etc/pyenv.d:/usr/lib/pyenv/hooks
+ [pyenv:100] export PYENV_HOOK_PATH
+ [pyenv:102] shopt -u nullglob
+ [pyenv:105] command=sh-activate
+ [pyenv:106] case "$command" in
++ [pyenv:119] command -v pyenv-sh-activate
+ [pyenv:119] command_path=/usr/local/bin/pyenv-sh-activate
+ [pyenv:120] '[' -n /usr/local/bin/pyenv-sh-activate ']'
+ [pyenv:122] shift 1
+ [pyenv:123] '[' --quiet = --help ']'
+ [pyenv:126] exec /usr/local/bin/pyenv-sh-activate --quiet
+ [pyenv-sh-activate:17] '[' -z /Users/DS/.pyenv ']'
+ [pyenv-sh-activate:25] unset FORCE
+ [pyenv-sh-activate:26] unset QUIET
+ [pyenv-sh-activate:27] unset VERBOSE
+ [pyenv-sh-activate:29] '[' 1 -gt 0 ']'
+ [pyenv-sh-activate:30] case "$1" in
+ [pyenv-sh-activate:44] QUIET=1
+ [pyenv-sh-activate:56] shift 1
+ [pyenv-sh-activate:29] '[' 0 -gt 0 ']'
+ [pyenv-sh-activate:59] no_shell=
+ [pyenv-sh-activate:60] versions=("$@")
+ [pyenv-sh-activate:61] '[' -z '' ']'
+ [pyenv-sh-activate:62] no_shell=1
+ [pyenv-sh-activate:63] OLDIFS='   
'
+ [pyenv-sh-activate:64] IFS=:
+ [pyenv-sh-activate:64] versions=($(pyenv-version-name 2>/dev/null))
++ [pyenv-sh-activate:64] pyenv-version-name
+ [pyenv-sh-activate:65] IFS='  
'
+ [pyenv-sh-activate:68] '[' -z 1 ']'
+ [pyenv-sh-activate:74] venv=system
+ [pyenv-sh-activate:76] '[' -n '' ']'
+ [pyenv-sh-activate:89] pyenv-virtualenv-prefix system
+ [pyenv-sh-activate:91] OLDIFS='   
'
+ [pyenv-sh-activate:92] IFS=:
+ [pyenv-sh-activate:92] current_versions=($(pyenv-version-name))
++ [pyenv-sh-activate:92] pyenv-version-name
+ [pyenv-version-name:6] '[' -z '' ']'
++ [pyenv-version-name:7] pyenv-version-file
+ [pyenv-version-file:22] find_local_version_file /Users/DS
+ [pyenv-version-file:7] local root=/Users/DS
+ [pyenv-version-file:8] true
+ [pyenv-version-file:9] [[ /Users/DS =~ ^//[^/]*$ ]]
+ [pyenv-version-file:10] '[' -e /Users/DS/.python-version ']'
+ [pyenv-version-file:13] '[' -e /Users/DS/.pyenv-version ']'
+ [pyenv-version-file:17] '[' -n /Users/DS ']'
+ [pyenv-version-file:18] root=/Users
+ [pyenv-version-file:8] true
+ [pyenv-version-file:9] [[ /Users =~ ^//[^/]*$ ]]
+ [pyenv-version-file:10] '[' -e /Users/.python-version ']'
+ [pyenv-version-file:13] '[' -e /Users/.pyenv-version ']'
+ [pyenv-version-file:17] '[' -n /Users ']'
+ [pyenv-version-file:18] root=
+ [pyenv-version-file:8] true
+ [pyenv-version-file:9] [[ '' =~ ^//[^/]*$ ]]
+ [pyenv-version-file:10] '[' -e /.python-version ']'
+ [pyenv-version-file:13] '[' -e /.pyenv-version ']'
+ [pyenv-version-file:17] '[' -n '' ']'
+ [pyenv-version-file:17] break
+ [pyenv-version-file:23] '[' /Users/DS = /Users/DS ']'
+ [pyenv-version-file:25] global_version_file=/Users/DS/.pyenv/version
+ [pyenv-version-file:27] '[' -e /Users/DS/.pyenv/version ']'
+ [pyenv-version-file:29] '[' -e /Users/DS/.pyenv/global ']'
+ [pyenv-version-file:31] '[' -e /Users/DS/.pyenv/default ']'
+ [pyenv-version-file:34] echo /Users/DS/.pyenv/version
+ [pyenv-version-name:7] PYENV_VERSION_FILE=/Users/DS/.pyenv/version
++ [pyenv-version-name:8] pyenv-version-file-read /Users/DS/.pyenv/version
+ [pyenv-version-file-read:6] VERSION_FILE=/Users/DS/.pyenv/version
+ [pyenv-version-file-read:8] '[' -e /Users/DS/.pyenv/version ']'
+ [pyenv-version-file-read:22] exit 1
++ [pyenv-version-name:8] true
+ [pyenv-version-name:8] PYENV_VERSION=
+ [pyenv-version-name:11] '[' -z '' ']'
+ [pyenv-version-name:12] echo system
+ [pyenv-version-name:13] exit
+ [pyenv-sh-activate:93] IFS='  
'
+ [pyenv-sh-activate:94] new_venv=system/envs/system
+ [pyenv-sh-activate:95] pyenv-virtualenv-prefix system/envs/system
+ [pyenv-sh-activate:99] '[' -z 1 ']'
+ [pyenv-sh-activate:102] echo false
+ [pyenv-sh-activate:103] exit 1
+_pyenv_virtualenv_hook:5> true
+_pyenv_virtualenv_hook:5> eval false
+(eval):1> false
+_pyenv_virtualenv_hook:5> true
+_pyenv_virtualenv_hook:7> return 0
+omz_termsupport_precmd:1> emulate -L zsh
+omz_termsupport_precmd:3> [[ '' == true ]]
+omz_termsupport_precmd:7> title '%15<..<%~%<<' %n@%m
+title:1> emulate -L zsh
+title:2> setopt prompt_subst
+title:4> [[ '' == *term* ]]
+title:8> : %n@%m
+title:10> case ansi (cygwin | xterm* | putty* | rxvt* | ansi)
+title:12> print -Pn '\e]2;%n@%m\a'
+title:13> print -Pn '\e]1;%15\<..\<%~%\<\<\a'
+update_terminalapp_cwd:1> emulate -L zsh
+update_terminalapp_cwd:4> omz_urlencode -P /Users/DS
+omz_urlencode:1> emulate -L zsh
+omz_urlencode:2> zparseopts -D -E -a opts r m P
+omz_urlencode:4> local 'in_str=/Users/DS'
+omz_urlencode:5> local 'url_str='
+omz_urlencode:6> local spaces_as_plus
+omz_urlencode:7> [[ -z -P ]]
+omz_urlencode:8> local 'str=/Users/DS'
+omz_urlencode:11> local 'encoding=UTF-8'
+omz_urlencode:12> local safe_encodings
+omz_urlencode:13> safe_encodings=( UTF-8 utf8 US-ASCII ) 
+omz_urlencode:14> [[ -z UTF-8 ]]
+omz_urlencode:23> local i byte ord 'LC_ALL=C'
+omz_urlencode:24> export LC_ALL
+omz_urlencode:25> local 'reserved=;/?:@&=+$,'
+omz_urlencode:26> local 'mark=_.!~*()-'
+omz_urlencode:27> local 'dont_escape=[A-Za-z0-9'
+omz_urlencode:28> [[ -z '' ]]
+omz_urlencode:29> dont_escape+=';/?:@&=+$,' 
+omz_urlencode:32> [[ -z '' ]]
+omz_urlencode:33> dont_escape+='_.!~*()-' 
+omz_urlencode:35> dont_escape+=']' 
+omz_urlencode:39> local 'url_str='
+omz_urlencode:40> i = 1
+omz_urlencode:40> i <= 9
+omz_urlencode:41> byte=/ 
+omz_urlencode:42> [[ "$byte" -regex-match "$dont_escape" ]]
+omz_urlencode:43> url_str+=/ 
+omz_urlencode:40> ++i 
+omz_urlencode:40> i <= 9
+omz_urlencode:41> byte=U 
+omz_urlencode:42> [[ "$byte" -regex-match "$dont_escape" ]]
+omz_urlencode:43> url_str+=U 
+omz_urlencode:40> ++i 
+omz_urlencode:40> i <= 9
+omz_urlencode:41> byte=s 
+omz_urlencode:42> [[ "$byte" -regex-match "$dont_escape" ]]
+omz_urlencode:43> url_str+=s 
+omz_urlencode:40> ++i 
+omz_urlencode:40> i <= 9
+omz_urlencode:41> byte=e 
+omz_urlencode:42> [[ "$byte" -regex-match "$dont_escape" ]]
+omz_urlencode:43> url_str+=e 
+omz_urlencode:40> ++i 
+omz_urlencode:40> i <= 9
+omz_urlencode:41> byte=r 
+omz_urlencode:42> [[ "$byte" -regex-match "$dont_escape" ]]
+omz_urlencode:43> url_str+=r 
+omz_urlencode:40> ++i 
+omz_urlencode:40> i <= 9
+omz_urlencode:41> byte=s 
+omz_urlencode:42> [[ "$byte" -regex-match "$dont_escape" ]]
+omz_urlencode:43> url_str+=s 
+omz_urlencode:40> ++i 
+omz_urlencode:40> i <= 9
+omz_urlencode:41> byte=/ 
+omz_urlencode:42> [[ "$byte" -regex-match "$dont_escape" ]]
+omz_urlencode:43> url_str+=/ 
+omz_urlencode:40> ++i 
+omz_urlencode:40> i <= 9
+omz_urlencode:41> byte=D 
+omz_urlencode:42> [[ "$byte" -regex-match "$dont_escape" ]]
+omz_urlencode:43> url_str+=D 
+omz_urlencode:40> ++i 
+omz_urlencode:40> i <= 9
+omz_urlencode:41> byte=S 
+omz_urlencode:42> [[ "$byte" -regex-match "$dont_escape" ]]
+omz_urlencode:43> url_str+=S 
+omz_urlencode:40> ++i 
+omz_urlencode:40> i <= 9
+omz_urlencode:53> echo -E /Users/DS
+update_terminalapp_cwd:4> local 'URL_PATH=/Users/DS'
+update_terminalapp_cwd:5> [[ 0 != 0 ]]
+update_terminalapp_cwd:8> printf '\e]7;%s\a' file://YuDaesungui-MacBook-Pro.local/Users/DS
+-zsh:5> build_prompt
+build_prompt:1> RETVAL=0 
+build_prompt:2> prompt_status
+prompt_status:1> local symbols
+prompt_status:2> symbols=( ) 
+prompt_status:3> [[ 0 -ne 0 ]]
+prompt_status:4> [[ 501 -eq 0 ]]
+prompt_status:5> [[+prompt_status:5> jobs -l
+prompt_status:5> [[+prompt_status:5> wc -l
+prompt_status:5> [[ '       0' -gt 0 ]]
+prompt_status:7> [[ -n '' ]]
+build_prompt:3> prompt_virtualenv
+prompt_virtualenv:1> local 'virtualenv_path='
+prompt_virtualenv:2> [[ -n '' ]]
+build_prompt:4> prompt_context
+prompt_context:1> [[ DS !=  ]]
+prompt_context:2> prompt_segment black default '%(!.%{%F{yellow}%}.)DS@%m'
+prompt_segment:1> local bg fg
+prompt_segment:2> [[ -n black ]]
+prompt_segment:2> bg='%K{black}' 
+prompt_segment:3> [[ -n default ]]
+prompt_segment:3> fg='%F{default}' 
+prompt_segment:4> [[ NONE != NONE ]]
+prompt_segment:7> echo -n '%{%K{black}%}%{%F{default}%} '
+prompt_segment:9> CURRENT_BG=black 
+prompt_segment:10> [[ -n '%(!.%{%F{yellow}%}.)DS@%m' ]]
+prompt_segment:10> echo -n '%(!.%{%F{yellow}%}.)DS@%m'
+build_prompt:5> prompt_dir
+prompt_dir:1> prompt_segment blue black '%~'
+prompt_segment:1> local bg fg
+prompt_segment:2> [[ -n blue ]]
+prompt_segment:2> bg='%K{blue}' 
+prompt_segment:3> [[ -n black ]]
+prompt_segment:3> fg='%F{black}' 
+prompt_segment:4> [[ black != NONE && blue != black ]]
+prompt_segment:5> echo -n ' %{%K{blue}%F{black}%}%{%F{black}%} '
+prompt_segment:9> CURRENT_BG=blue 
+prompt_segment:10> [[ -n '%~' ]]
+prompt_segment:10> echo -n '%~'
+build_prompt:6> prompt_git
+prompt_git:1> ((  1  ))
+prompt_git:2> local PL_BRANCH_CHAR
+prompt_git:3> '(anon)'
+(anon):1> local 'LC_ALL=' 'LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8'
+(anon):2> PL_BRANCH_CHAR= 
+prompt_git:7> local ref dirty mode repo_path
+prompt_git:8> repo_path=+prompt_git:8> git rev-parse --git-dir
+prompt_git:8> repo_path='' 
+prompt_git:10> git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree

+build_prompt:7> prompt_bzr
+prompt_bzr:1> ((  0  ))
+prompt_bzr:1> return
+build_prompt:8> prompt_hg
+prompt_hg:1> ((  0  ))
+prompt_hg:1> return
+build_prompt:9> prompt_end
+prompt_end:1> [[ -n blue ]]
+prompt_end:2> echo -n ' %{%k%F{blue}%}'
+prompt_end:6> echo -n '%{%f%}'
+prompt_end:7> CURRENT_BG='
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about shell customization and belongs on apple or unix/linux stack exchanges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was **kaspersky** program :(
I did not matter with pyenv and zsh

Comment: *kaspersky*? I can understand.